Python command just hangs in the command prompt
I am having trouble getting python up and running again. It used to be working fine on my desktop, but I messed something up with virtual environments, and now I cannot even get a simple python command to run. I am on Windows 10.
I uninstalled python by going to Settings > Apps & features > uninstall and then reinstalled the latest version 3.12.3 from python.org.
Now, I run where python in the command prompt and it returns
C:\Users\Owner\env-pymongo-fastapi-crud\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

And when I run python app.py where I have an app.py script the command just hangs, nothing happens. I used to be able to run this script with python app.py, but now it doesn't work. When I run python and python --version in the command prompt, the command also hangs.
In my System variables I have both
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\scripts
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Within the actual directory C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\scripts there are python files but no python.exe. Within C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps there is both a python.exe and python3.exe.
I also have a directory C:\Python310\ that contains python.exe and pyvenv.cfg.
So I have three python.exe files in 3 different spots; I feel this may be causing the error. Anyways any help is appreciated.

When you ran where python and it returned 2 paths, the second path is one I can confirm is normal... The first is not... Therefore try this: Run python with this path instead of just calling python C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe (where your Owner is whatever user you are using. Just running that command should give you a python terminal... If that's the case then you need to remove the first path to python as it's what's causing the hang.

Ok I removed the other path env-pymongo completely and now it works. Didn't know it would be that easy!

Glad I could help direct you in the right direction.
